# PHP having multiple "child" arrays within "parent" array and how to access them

Tags: php, arrays

i am trying to create an array which stores various photo albums,

so far i have the following code

```
$photos = array(
            array("karate","1","2"),
            array("judo","1","2"),
            array("kickboxing","1","2"),
            array("womenselfdefense","1","2")
            );

$sections = array("karate","judo","kickboxing","womenselfdefense");
foreach($sections as $keys => $section)
{
    echo count($photos[$section]);
}
```

but i dont think i have set up my arrays properly, ideally i'd like the main array $photos to have 4 separate arrays $karate,$judo,$kickboxing,$womenselfdefense within it.

i want to start of by counting the number of items in each array and then choose a random item within each array, however i believe at the moment i have 4 unnamed arrays within the photos array and therefor my code returns several Undefined index: errors

can anyone help me with this please

Comment: We don't understand what's the purpose of this?

Comment: Do a `print_r($photos)` that should show you your mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the name of the photo album as the key for the photos array.

```
$photos = array(
    "karate" => array("1","2"),
    "judo" => array("1","2"),
    "kickboxing" => array("1","2"),
    "womenselfdefense" => array("1","2")
);
$sections = array("karate","judo","kickboxing","womenselfdefense");
foreach($sections as $keys => $section)
{
    echo count($photos[$section]).'<br>';
}
```

Comment: But you have changed the array to suite YOUR purposes. Thats not answering the OP's question

Comment: this looks promising, will try it out later when i get home, many thanks!!!

Comment: @RiggsFolly I did not suit my purposes. He still has 4 separate array, however they are identified by the keyword.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for an [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), which uses a label instead of a number as a key:

```
$photos = array(
    "karate" => array("1","2"),
    "judo" => array("1","2"),
    "kickboxing" => array("1","2"),
    "womenselfdefense" => array("1","2")
);

foreach ($photos as $section=>$values) {
    //now $values is your array of numbers
    echo count($values);
}
```

Or, in modern syntax:

```
$photos = [
    "karate" => [1, 2],
    "judo" => [1, 2],
    "kickboxing" => [1, 2],
    "womenselfdefense" => [1, 2],
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the arrays without assigning the higher level arrays any keys.

Try something like this:

```
$photos = array(
    'karate' => array("karate","1","2"),
    'judo' => array("judo","1","2"),
    'kickboxing' => array("kickboxing","1","2"),
    'womenselfdefense' => array("womenselfdefense","1","2")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to use

```
 echo count($photos[$keys]);
```